# Microsoft IDL, Change attributes on an interface

Tags: c++, object, com, vb6, ole-automation

some time ago I prepared an idl file to define the interface for plugins of a VB6 application.

Reviewing code I found there is an interface which looks like this:

```
[
    odl,
    uuid(<some guid>),
    version(1.0),
    nonextensible, oleautomation
]
interface IPlugin : IUnknown {
    HRESULT DoSomething();
}
```

This interface is used in some VB6 and C++ components (dlls) to expose the main plugin class, also the exe refers to the typelibrary to keep a reference of plugin classes.

What I would like to do now is to remove **odl**, **version** and **nonextensible** because not required, and then add the **object** attribute to correctly define a COM interface.

- Now that the entire system is in production, can I change attributes on the interface?
- Can I do it without compatibility issues?

Thank you

Comment: Given that it works now, changing these attributes is very unlikely to be breaking.  You can't get a warranty here.